# Any link for Dojo sliding panel?

Tags: dojo

Can anyone help me with a link where I find Dojo sliding panel ? I have been searching for it but still didn't got it. I have sliding panel for jQuery, I got it from this link : http://web-kreation.com/all/implement-a-nice-clean-jquery-sliding-panel-in-wordpress-27/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of the dojo.fx.wipeIn functionality.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/fx/wipeIn.html

So if you create two divs, one above the other, have the top one with display: none, and the other as the bit that you click to slide the panel down. Then use dojo.connect to link the clicking of the bottom panel to a wipe in of your top panel.

e.g.

```
// Have your main body content
var mainBody;

// Create top panel
var myPanel = document.createElement("div");

// Set visibility to none
dojo.style(myPanel, "display", "none");

// Create tab to expand your panel (or slide it down)
var expand = document.createElement("div");
expand.innerHTML = "click here to slide down";

mainBody.appendChild(myPanel);      
mainBody.appendChild(expand);

var self = this;

dojo.connect(expand, "onclick", this, slidePanel);
```

Then you'd have your slidePanel function do something like:

```
// Get reference to your panel
var myPanel;

var wipeArgs = {
    node: myPanel
};

// Then just wipe the panel in or out respectively
if (myPanel.style.display == "none") {
    dojo.fx.wipeIn(wipeArgs).play();
} else {
    dojo.fx.wipeOut(wipeArgs).play();
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with how to put these things together ? I will be very thankful.